# How can I determine the amount of time a rvest query is for the http response

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I have been using the rvest package to perform screen scraping for some data analytics, but there are some queries that are taking a few seconds each to actually collect the data. e.g.

```
  sectorurl = paste("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=,",ticker,"+Profile", sep= "")
  index <- read_html( sectorurl)
```

The second step is that one that is taking the time, so I was wondering if there were any diagnostics in the background of R or a clever package that could be run that will determine "network wait time" as opposed to CPU time, or something similar.

I would like to know if I'm stuck with the performance I have, or if actually my R code is performing well and it is http response that is limiting my process speed.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a utility to capture and log all http traffic outside of R. Something like this perhaps: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to separate the REST call from the client side code.  However, my experience with accessing web services is that the network time generally dominates the total running time, with the "CPU" time being an order of magnitude, or more, less.

One option for you to try would be to paste your URL, which appears to be a GET, into a web browser and see how long it takes to complete from the console.  You can compare this time against the total time taken in R for the same call.  For this, try using `system.time`, which returns the CPU time used by a given expression.

```
require(stats)
system.time(read_html(sectorurl))
```

Check out the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.time.html) for more information.